# react-accessible-treeview expand nodes dynamically added

Tags: javascript, reactjs, treeview

I'm using react-accessible-treeview component adding\removing nodes dynamically dragging nodes from a tree view to another.
When a node is dropped to destination tree, all parents is added too, the problem is that i want to expand the dropped node and all its parents.
I tried to work with the property "expandedIds", it woks but is some nodes will be expand with mouse click the "expandedIds" state is not updated by the component and, when the next node will be dropped the "mouse clicked" expanded node collapse.
What is the way to achieve the right behavior?